# Angular routing tutorial issue

Tags: angular

I'm working on this very basic Angular tutorial and I'm in the routing part of the tutorial. When clicking on the product name, it should open a page with the product details. However, it only shows the text "Product Details". Why doesn't it work?

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

This is the content of app-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { TopBarComponent } from "./top-bar/top-bar.component";
import { ProductListComponent } from "./product-list/product-list.component";
import { ProductAlertsComponent } from "./product-alerts/product-alerts.component";
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from "./product-details/product-details.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: "products/:productId", component: ProductDetailsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductAlertsComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's Product-list.component.html

```
<h2>Products</h2>

<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <h3>
    <a
      [title]="product.name + ' details'"
      [routerLink]="['/products', productId]"
    >
      {{ product.name }}
    </a>
  </h3>

  <p *ngIf="product.description">Description: {{ product.description }}</p>

  <button (click)="share()">
    Share
  </button>

  <app-product-alerts [product]="product" (notify)="onNotify()">
  </app-product-alerts>

  <app-product-alerts [product]="product"> </app-product-alerts>
</div>
```

This is product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { products } from "../products";

@Component({
  selector: "app-product-list",
  templateUrl: "./product-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./product-list.component.css"]
})
export class ProductListComponent {
  products = products;

  share() {
    window.alert("The product has been shared!");
  }

  onNotify() {
    window.alert("You will be notified when the product goes on sale");
  }
}
```

What am I missing? The instructions are pretty straight forward at https://angular.io/start/routing

Product-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"; 
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router"; 
import { products } from "../products"; 

@Component
 ({ selector: "app-product-details",
    templateUrl: "./product-details.component.html", 
    styleUrls: ["./product-details.component.css"] }) 


export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit { 
           product; 
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {} 

    ngOnInit() { 
       this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
                          params => { this.product = 
                                 products[+params.get("productId")]; }); 
             } }
```

Product-details.component.html:

```
<h2>Product Details</h2>

<div *ngIf="product">
  <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
  <h4>{{ product.price | currency }}</h4>
  <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
</div>
```

App-module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { TopBarComponent } from "./top-bar/top-bar.component";
import { ProductListComponent } from "./product-list/product-list.component";
import { ProductAlertsComponent } from "./product-alerts/product-alerts.component";
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from "./product-details/product-details.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: "products/:productId", component: ProductDetailsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductAlertsComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Is it throwing back to home route?

Comment: Did you use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the template (i.e `app.component.html` that you want to display this component? Also, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: According to the route when you click on the product it opens the product details component. So what's in that component?

Comment: @Ramesh: Looks like this is the template `Product-list.component.html`

Comment: @NicholasK that's the template for `productListComponent` but for the path `products/:productId` the component was `ProductDetailsComponent`.

Comment: @Mridul Sorry I don't get what you mean!  And yes, I have 
`<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>`
in app.component.html. Console does not show any errors. These are the contents of product-details.component.html:
`<h2>Product Details</h2>

<div *ngIf="product">
  <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
  <h4>{{ product.price | currency }}</h4>
  <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
</div>`

Sorry for the horrible formatting but this is the comment field..

Comment: @mntbnk can we have a look at product details component ts file ?

Comment: @mntblnk did you register routes in `app.module.ts` as well do you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`..Please share code for `ProductDetailsComponent` as well to check how you're rendering product Details

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the contents of product-details.component.html and .ts files as well as app.module.ts.

Comment: try `[routerLink]="['/products', product.productId]"` (productId is nothing)

Comment: @Eliseo Did not do anything.

Comment: @mntblnk in the product details component add `console.log(this.product)` after `this.product = products[+params.get("productId")];` and see if you are getting the clicked product in the console. If not then the only way we can help you would be if you create a stackblitz of your app. Also, can you show us the product array?

Comment: @mntblnk Your `product-list.component.html` isn't the same from https://angular.io/start/routing#registering-a-route where they have already defined `index as productId`. I tried it myself just now and your route is going to `/products/undefined` instead of the desired index.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the rest of the product details because the `productId` is undefined in your template.

In the tutorial for simplicity, he's considering the index of each product as `productId`.

So in the `Product-list.component.html` the structural directive should be used like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; index as productId">
```

the `index as productId` part will assign the index's value to the productId variable so that you can use it in the `routerLink` property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in this but I think I figured it out. Look at this line of code that's shown in tutorial:

```
   <a [title]="product.name + ' details'" [routerLink]="['/products', product.id]">
```

product.id is supposed field in objects in array of objects exported from app/products.ts. You would notice we don't have such field, so  you just need to add it like this:

```
export const products = [
  {
    name: 'Phone XL',
    price: 799,
    description: 'A large phone with one of the best screens',
    id: 'thisisID1', // this is added
  },
  {
    name: 'Phone Mini',
    price: 699,
    description: 'A great phone with one of the best cameras',
    id: 'thisisID2', // this is added
  },
  {
    name: 'Phone Standard',
    price: 299,
    description: '',
    id: 'thisisID3', // this is added
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

change **productId to productid**
It is due to case sensitive typo in the tutorial document.

In **products.ts** we have id as small case as below,

```
id: 1,
name: 'Phone XL',
price: 799,
description: 'A large phone with one of the best screens',
```

But in **product-details-component.ts -> ngOnInit()** method the doc guides to add as below,
....
const productIdFromRoute = Number(routeParams.get('productId'));
....
Just change **productId to productid** as below,
....
const productIdFromRoute = Number(routeParams.get('**productid**'));
....
This fixed the issue.